# Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2 Error And Use LINQ statement to get values of JObject

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

```
{"type" : "Something", 
 "values" : [ 
 { "type": "Something else", 
   "Categories": { 
       "values": [ "Grocery" ]},
   "Origin": {
       "values": [
          {
             "Name": "Chicken",
             "State": "Texas",
             "Quantity": "200",
             "Year" : "2017" }],
  "Primaryprovider": "Farmer",
  "Name": "EggsGrocery"
}, 
{ 
  "type": "Something else",
  "categories": { 
      "values": [ "Utensil" ]},
  "Origin": {
       "values": [
          {
             "Name": "Cutlery",
             "State": "Alaska",
             "Quantity": "109",
             "Year" : "2015" }],
  "Primaryprovider": "Welder",
  "Name": "UtensilSpoon"
}]}
```

I have a dictionary that matches the category with the name. So I try to get the Primaryproviders and I get this;

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken,Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]
```

Please help me point out what I'm doing wrong. And how can I get the Origin values of Name, State and Year if the state is Texas with a LINQ expression? I'm not very proficient with LINQ so I'd really appreciate a short explanation there. I started to use JToken for that and I've seen that it's a bad idea. 
Please help. Thanks alot in advance!

```
 foreach (var kvp in catDict)
        {
            string cat = kvp.Key;
            List<string> Names = new List<string>();
            Names.AddRange(kvp.Value);
            for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
            {
                 //if the name contains the name of the category
                if (Names[i].Contains(cat))
                {
                    //get primaryprovider
                    string primaryprover = json["values"].Select(pk => pk.SelectToken("Primaryprovider")).ToString();

             // get the Origin Name, State & year if the state is Texas
             // foreach (var jent in json["values"])
                //{  
                    //if (jentity["Origin"]["State"] == "Texas")
                //}

                    Console.WriteLine(primaryprovider);
                }
```

Comment: `Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator\`2` is not an "error". It is the string returned by `ToString()` on the result of `Select()`. When `ToString` is not overridden for a type you get it's name. In this case you have a nested type (`WhereSelectEnumerableIterator` is a nested class of the `Enumerable` class). It also includes 2 (`\`2`) generic arguments. This is not an answer to your question; I am pointing this out so that you can recognize these mystery strings in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: Since not all the code is provided I have to make some assumptions about the objects. For example, what are the generic arguments of catDict?

One thing that stands out is that the `string primaryProvider` doesn't use any of the loop variables, meaning it will always return the same value.

But my advice would be to back up and take a different approach. [Deserialize your json into a list of objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data) (you'll need to create the data contract first). Once that's done, your methods for the operations you discussed are very simple. Here are some examples.

```
//get and declare seralizer, then deserialize
List<Item> items = serializer.Deserialize<Item>().ToList();

//find a specific item by name
string searchName = "UtensilSpoon";
var mySearchItem = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == searchName); //null if not found

//get all the items from a given primary provider
string primaryProvider = "Farmer";
var mySearchItems = items.Where(i => i.Primaryprovider == primaryProvider);

//get all the items in a given category
string category = "Grocery";
var itemsInCategory = items.Where(i => i.Categories.Contains(category));

//get the origin object for items in a given state
string state = "Texas";
var texasItems = items.Where(i => i.Origin.State == state);

//print out the item name, state, and year for texas items only
string state = "Texas";
foreach (var item in items.Where(i => i.Origin.State == state))  //(var item in texasItems) would also work
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Origin.State);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Origin.Year);
}
```